# Applying an operation on each element of nested list

Tags: kdb

I have a complex nested list (depth can be >2 also):

```
p:((`g;`d1`d2);(`r;enlist `e1);(`r;enlist `p1))
```

How to add an element to each element of the nested list but retaining the original structure; e.g. adding `` `h `` to each element of `p` to get the following :

```
((`g`h;(`d1`h;`d2`h));(`r`h;enlist `e1`h);(`r`h;enlist `p1`h))
```

I tried this but doesn't give what I want :

```
q)p,\:`h
((`g;`d1`d2;`h);(`r;enlist `e1;`h);(`r;enlist `p1;`h))

q)raze[p],\:`h
(`g`h;`d1`d2`h;`r`h;`e1`h;`r`h;`p1`h)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.z.s`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zs-self) to recursively go through the nested list and only append `` `h `` to lists of symbols:

```
q){$[0=type x;.z.s'[x];x,\:`h]}p
g    h    d1 h d2 h
`r`h      ,`e1`h
`r`h      ,`p1`h
```

For this function I have made the assumption that your nested lists will only contain symbols. It checks the type of the list, if it is not a mixed list then it appends `` `h `` to each element. If it is a mixed list then it passes each element of that list back into the function separately to check again.

Answer (score 2):

Although not recursive (and so requires some knowledge about the shape of your nested list), a more conventional approach would be

```
q).[p;2#(::);,';`h]
g    h    d1 h d2 h
`r`h      ,`e1`h
`r`h      ,`p1`h
```

Answer (score 1):

Though Thomas has already answered the question; In case you want to specify any other operation apart from `append`, you can use the following :

```
q)f:{`$ "_" sv string x,y}

q){[o;a;e] $[-11<>type e; .z.s [o;a] each e; o[e;a]] }[f;`h] each p
`g_h `d1_h`d2_h
`r_h ,`e1_h
`r_h ,`p1_h
```

or when `f` is assigned as `append` operation

```
q)f:{x,y}
q){[o;a;e] $[-11<>type e; .z.s [o;a] each e; o[e;a]] }[f;`h] each p
g    h    d1 h d2 h
`r`h      ,`e1`h
`r`h      ,`p1`h
```